# Swift - fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None

Tags: uitableview, core-data, swift, ios8

I am trying to fetch Core data objects and display them in UITableView.

I have `DBEmployess` object, when I try to get its `name` property I get an error

```
fatal error: Can't unwrap Optional.None
```

Here is my code

**DBEmployess.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class DBProjects;

@interface DBEmployess : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * designation;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * age;
@property (nonatomic, retain) DBProjects *projects;

@end
```

**DBEmployess.m**

```
#import "DBEmployess.h"
#import "DBProjects.h"


@implementation DBEmployess

@dynamic name;
@dynamic designation;
@dynamic age;
@dynamic projects;

@end
```

**MyProject-Bridging-Header.h**

```
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"
#import "DBEmployess.h"
```

**UITableView Method**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell : UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as? UITableViewCell
    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    let employee : DBEmployess? = self.employessArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? DBEmployess

    if(employee != nil) {
        cell!.textLabel.text = employee!.valueForKey("name").description
    }

    return cell!
}
```

If I print `employee` object, I get

```
(DBEmployess?) employee = Some {
  Some = 0x0000000111702670 {
    CoreData.NSManagedObject = {
      ObjectiveC.NSObject = {}
    }
  }
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

**Update:**

I found that the actual problem is while saving Core data. If I set hard-coded strings in `NSManagedObject`'s property, it is accessible perfectly and is displaying in UITableView. But if I set the value of `UITextField` text, it does successfully saved but can't unwrapped.

Here is my Core Data methoed

```
func addNewEmployee() {
    let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let context = delegate.managedObjectContext
    let newManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("DBEmployess", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject
    newManagedObject.setValue(self.txtName.text, forKey: "name")
    newManagedObject.setValue(self.txtDesignation.text, forKey: "designation")
    newManagedObject.setValue(self.txtAge.text, forKey: "age")

    // Save the context.
    var error: NSError? = nil
    if !context.save(&error) {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Could not save employee \(error!.localizedDescription)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Saved", message: "Employee saved successfully", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: if you optional object is `nil` you cannot unwrap it; otherwise you get the crash as you have already got. it is true for the `cell` and for the `employee`. which line throws the exception?

Comment: I have println() DBEmployess, and it doesn't seem to be null. You can see log in my question.

Comment: so, let me try again, which line throws the exepction?

Comment: I have updated the question to check for nil. Trying to get value of employee object causes the error `employee!.valueForKey("name").description`

Comment: I cannot access `name` property

Comment: @Khawar "I cannot access `name` property" That's because it looks like the property is not there.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, thanks for reply. I forgot to mention 1 more thing, my Core Data class is in Objective-C. I have imported it in Bridging-Header.h file. Could that make trouble?

Comment: If `name` is `nil`, this will error because `valueForKey` returns an optional. I believe you should try `if let name = employee?.valueForKey("name") { cell!.textLabel.text = name } else { // NO NAME! }`

Comment: Jack Wu beat me to it - try "if let" with the optional, which should help with the initial unwrapping error ...
 
Unrelated, and I don't mean to offend, but you seem to have misspelled "employess" throughout the code. It's consistent & so not broken, but the correct spelling should be "employees." If you wind up sharing the code w/others this may become a source of errors/confusion... If it's just you, then never mind :)

Comment: I have updated the question, the problem is actually in saving Core Data. Please have a look.